# How to select an element (Text, View) in react-native with jest+enzyme (mostly when Text/View are nested deep-down in the component)?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme, jest-enzyme

I know of something called `find` in enzyme, but I'd like to know how to select a react-native element by some attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select it by any attribute like `id`, e.g,

for selecting the following Text in `testing.js`

```
<Text id="myid">hello </Text>
```

you can do the following

```
it('selects Text with id attr', () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(<Testing />);
  let text = wrapper.findWhere(node => node.name() === 'Text' && node.prop('id') === 'myid');
  console.log(text.debug());
})
```